# Multiple loops logic and speed optimization in Python?

Tags: python

Here is two python functions to transfer data from one file to another file. Both source file and target file have the same number of objects but with different data.

```
def getBlock(rigObj, objName):
    rigObj.seek(0)
    Tag = False
    block = ""
    for line in rigObj:
        if line.find("ObjectAlias " + str(objName) + "\n") != -1:
            for line in rigObj:
                if line.find("BeginKeyframe") != -1:
                    Tag = True
                elif line.lstrip().startswith("0.000 ") and line.rstrip().endswith("default"):
                    Tag = False
                    break
                elif Tag:
                    block += line
    return (block)

def buildScene(sceneObj, rigObj, objList):
    sceneObj.seek(0)
    rigObj.seek(0)
    newscene = ""
    for line in sceneObj:
        newscene += line
        for obj in objList:
            if line.find("ObjectAlias " + obj + "\n") != -1:
                Tag = True
                for line in sceneObj:
                    if line.find("BeginKeyframe") != -1:
                        newscene += line
                        newscene += getBlock(rigObj, obj)
                        Tag = False
                    elif line.lstrip().startswith("0.000 ") and line.rstrip().endswith("default"):
                        newscene += line
                        Tag = True
                        break
                    elif Tag:
                        newscene += line
    return (newscene)
```

**getBlock** is a sub-function for getting data from rigobj;
**buildScene** is my main function, it has three parameters:
First parameter(sceneobj) is the file that I want to put data into;
Second parameter(rigobj) is the file that I get the data from;
Third parameter(objlist) is a list of what object's data to be transfered.

So far, the function does its job, the only problem is a bit of slow(sceneobj<10MB, rigobj<2MB, objlist<10 objects), I am not sure if there are a logic problem in the code, should I loop the sceneObj first or loop the objList first? Does it affect the speed?

**UPDATE:**
Both sceneObj and rigObj have similar data like this:

```
lines
BeginObject               
lines                     
ObjectAlias xxx           #--> object in transfer list
lines                     
BeginKeyframe 10 12       
  -9.000 4095 default     #--> transfer begins
  lines                   #--> transfer from rigObj to sceneObj and override lines in sceneObj
  -8.000 63 default       #--> same
  lines                   #--> same
  -7.000 63 default       #--> same
  lines                   #--> same
  -1.000 63 default       #--> same
  lines                   #--> transfer ends
  0.000 -1 default        
  lines                   
EndKeyframe               
EndMotion                 
lines                     
EndObject
```

The data want to be transfered and overrided is only lines bewteen **BeginKeyframe** and **0.000 -1 default** of any specified objects(by objList)

Comment: Can you add profiler result, and example of input data?

Comment: @Arnial updated my post

Comment: Is it possible that rigObj has same ObjectAlias multiple times but with different data?

Comment: @Arnial I am not quite sure what you mean. But the sceneObj consist of rigObj with more extra data, so each object exist in rigObj should be existed in sceneObj.

Answer (score 0):

Most obvious optimization is to index data for `getBlock` function, so you will able to seek to needed position instead of always parsing full file from  beginning.

like so:

```
def create_rig_index(rig_obj):
    """ This function creates dict of offsets for specific ObjectAlias
         Example:
              data: 
                   line with offset 100: ObjectAlias xxx
                   more lines
                   line with offset 200: ObjectAlias yyy
                   more lines
                   line with offset 300: ObjectAlias xxx
                   more lines

              result will be:
                   xxx: [100, 300]
                   yyy: [200]
    """
    idx = defaultdict( list )
    position = 0
    for line in rig_obj:
        strip_line = line.strip()
        if strip_line.startswith( "ObjectAlias" ):
            obj_name = strip_line.split()[1]
            idx[ obj_name ].append( position )

        # unfortunately python prevent `tell` calls during iteration.
        position += len( bytes( line, 'utf-8' ) ) 
        # if data guaranteed to be ascii only its possible to use len( line )
        # or you can write custom line generator on top of read function.
    return idx;

def getBlock(rigObj, rigIdx, objName):
    """ same as your getBlock, but uses precalculated offsets"""
    block = ""
    for idx in rigIdx[ objName ]:
        rigObj.seek( idx )
        Tag = False
        for line in rigObj:
            if line.find("BeginKeyframe") != -1:
                Tag = True
            elif line.lstrip().startswith("0.000 ") and line.rstrip().endswith("default"):
                break
            elif Tag:
                block += line

    return (block)
```

In buildScene method you should create rig_index before running for loop, and use this index in `getBlock` function.

Comment: Thanks for help. From what you mean, my code didn't has any logic problem, and the most time-waste part is getBlock searching(I totally agree about this), right? I have an question about `if line.find("ObjectAlias " + obj + "\n") != -1:` in **buildScene**, if a line don't not start with **ObjectAlias**, will the code still interate in `for obj in objList`?

Comment: Yes it will iterate over `objList` even if line don't start with "ObjectAlias".

Comment: Also you can use `"ObjectAlias " + obj + "\n" in line` instead of `line.find("ObjectAlias" + obj + "\n") != -1`. Python docs asks to not use `in` operator instead of [find](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find).

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. So if I add a line something like `if line.startswith("ObjectAlias "):` before `for obj in objList:`, will it help to speed-up a bit?

Comment: Thanks, I am quite new to programming, I have to spend some time to figure out your code, hopefully it will speed up.